# Adding time, lat &nd lat dimension to .nc file (VHP.G04.C07.NC.P1981035.SM.nc)

Tags: python

I downloaded vegetation health data from the NOAA FTP service **(VHP.G04.C07.NC.P1981035.SM.nc)**. Each file has **'HEIGHT': 3616, 'WIDTH': 10000** as dimension.

The major issue is that the data has come 3/weekly without a time dimension except that each file is labeled with the date for which the data was acquired.

When I read the file normally:

```
file = (r'HP.G04.C07.NC.P1981035.SM.nc')
```

It opens normally but does not allow for any other operation, other than to just view the dims.

When I follow a tutorial of reading the file to see if I can add the missing (lat,lon) dimensions i.e :

```
file = Dataset('VHP.G04.C07.NC.P1981035.SM.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
```

I recieve errors `(Permission denied: b'D:\x02ND_ARTICLE_II\trials\\VHP.G04.C07.NC.P1981035.SM.nc')`

Please I need help in adding the missing dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have write permission over the file. Please refer [this](https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/drives-establishing-windows-file-and-folder-level-permissions/) article to grant write permission to the file.

Comment: the article did not open in my browser. It was blocked by the Institutions as unsafe.

Comment: Corrected it now!